# Removing inline CSS affects styles defined in stylesheet

Tags: javascript, css, attributes, getcomputedstyle

I'm facing a strange behavior.

I have a script that applies **inline CSS** to elements from its stylesheet with `computedStyle` method.

This is a way to copy **rich text** instead of **plain text**.

But after the copy, I need to delete the `style=""` attribute.

When this happens, some style attributes (like `color`, disappears) while I can see in the inspector that this attribute is still linked to my element by its `class`.

**See there :** 
https://jsfiddle.net/sxybrcug/ (`color` disappears but `border-color` is okay)

Do you know what's happening ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like inline styles are being added to your `container` div as well, but on the button click, only the inline styles on the `<p>` elements are removed. So `p` continues to inherit the inline styles of `container`, specifically, `-webkit-text-fill-color`, which is set to black, overriding the `color` property.

If you add

```
container.setAttribute("style", "");
```

to your click listener, it removes all the inline styles and the color of the `p` elements shows as red.

Comment: It seems to work when I add you line of code ! However I need to keep style on my container. But why does `<p>` inherits ? It has its own color property from its class.

Comment: `p` only has the `color` property set, not `-webkit-text-fill-color`. So it inherits this value from its parent. Between `-webkit-text-fill-color` and `color`, `webkit-text-fill-color` takes precedence (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-fill-color)

Comment: If you want to keep all the inline-styles you already have on the container, you can add `-webkit-text-fill-color: #f00;` to your `red` class in css, to override just that property

Comment: Oh and also it inherits that property from its parent `container` because inline-styles take priority. So it needs to be explicitly overridden with more specificity.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you know any other proprietary (or not) properties that might override inline style ? Like, you mentioned `-webkit-text-fill-color` but I suppose there must be others ?

Comment: It's not so much that the `-webkit-text-fill-color` overrides the inline-style (`p` has no more inline-styles after the button is clicked), just that the property is present in the inline-style of the parent container, so is inherited by the  children `p`. 
Or do you mean are there any other properties the `container` is passing down that might interfere with the border and color properties set with css on the `p` elements?